# Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '5.0.0', apply: false] was not found

Tags: android, android-studio, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I updated today Android Studio to Giraffe. I found that the [latest version](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/tree/master/google-services-plugin) for `com.google.gms.google-services` is 5.0.0

When I try to sync the project, I get this error:

> Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '5.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Here are all my plugins:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '5.0.0' apply false
}
```

If I downgrade to '4.3.15' version, everything works fine.

How to overcome this error?

Comment: Update your question to confirm if you have added the plugins gradlePluginPortal()
        google()

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez Yes, I can conform I have both plugins present inside the settings.gradle file.

Comment: I believe that is a bug on Google. That version does not exist yet.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez Then what is the latest version?

Comment: Based here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gms/google-services?repo=google it is still v4.3.15. Our codebase is still on this version too.

Comment: You're welcome, have a nice day ahead.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez You too, Lawrence.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following dependency to the root `build.gradle` file:

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:5.0.0'`

Comment: It doesn't work either. I get `Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:5.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
**1st Method**

Add this to gradle
implementation 'com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:4.3.15'

**2nd Method**
-> Go to  Project Structure
-> Dependencies then Library Dependencies 
-> Click on + and Paste this com.google.gms.google-services
-> Tap on Search
-> Add available depe
```

Comment: It seems to me that the latest version of the library is `4.3.15`. Why is then mentioned that `5.0.0` is the latest version?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).